# Difference between「なんか」and「なんだか」?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, etymology, syntax

What are some examples of their usage? Is なん the short form of 何【なに】 in both words?

Also, not sure if this is correct, but the だ in the middle of なんだか should be the copula. Why is the copula being used like this in the middle of a word?

Answer (score 4):

なんだか is three words なん + だ + か but it's become a set phrase and is used as a word itself pretty much to express an idea like *somehow, somewhat,* or *rather*.

> 今日はなんだかさむい

> It's rather cold today.

なんか is different with a couple of different uses.  It's usually an informal version of なにか or など.

> なんか冷たいものが飲みたい。

> I want something cold to drink.

Or

> 絵や音楽なんかに興味がない

> I have no interest in things like painting and music.

Comment: なんか and なんだか are interchangeable when they mean *somehow*, e.g., 今日はなんか寒い and 今日はなんだか寒い are very close.

Comment: @naruto Thank you.  I was also wondering about formality when it comes to なんだか.  It doesn't seem to me there is a fixed expression to use for なんだか in a more formal setting.  It seems to me that in a *formal setting* different expressions need to be used on a case by case basis.  Am I right?

Comment: なんか is very informal and should be avoided in almost any formal setting, whereas なんだか is fine in day-to-day business settings. In very formal settings, we can use どうも, いくぶん, いささか, どういうわけか, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[なにか](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B_%28%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B%29/#jn-164507) can mean *something* as well as *somehow* while [なんだか](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B/#jn-165831) is always the adverb *somehow*. なんか is a less formal, more colloquial version of なにか with its に changed to ん (cf. [撥音便](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#%E6%92%A5%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF))

Although だ should be etymologically the copula, but as you can see in the link, it would be simpler to consider them as independent words on their own.

Some examples:

- なんだか悲しい気分だ = なんか悲しい気分だ *I feel sad for some reason*
- なんか食べたい *I want something to eat*